# Finding the Maximum Cut of undirected graph using Stoer-Wagner algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

Can I use Stoer-Wagner algorithm to find the max cut?
Say, I negate all weights of the edges and find the minimum cut of this graph using  Stoer-Wagner algorithm, is the result cut a max cut of the original graph?

**Added**: In Stoer-Wagner algorithm, what if I choose the least tightly connected vertex instead, and choose the largest among all cut returned by cut-of-the-phase, is it the global maximum cut? Why or Why not? Any example?

Comment: Max Cut is an NP-hard problem. So, no you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Nico's observation that max cut is hard is the general reason that approaches like this one probably won't work, but the specific problem is that, when Stoer--Wagner goes to find an st min cut, the max flow routine that it most likely calls can't find a flow at all, since all of the capacities are negative. (Max flow algorithms can handle negative capacities in case there's a way to circulate flow to eliminate the negative capacities and get a feasible flow, but if they're all negative, then there's no way.)

Comment: @KevinLing That's the customary way to find the initial st min cut.